# Lambda maintaining checkpoint across deployments

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I've got a Lambda deployed by CloudFormation that consumes from Kinesis and produces to another Kinesis stream. The consumer of the output topic doesn't handle duplicate records well so I wanted to understand more how Lambda keeps the state of the last record/batch it consumed.

- When redeploying lambda is the information maintaned? Or it starts reading from the StartingPosition?
- When redeploying the Lambda via CF what difference would there be if the type of change done to the resource is `Update` vs `Replacement`? My gut feeling is that position is maintained when it's an `Update`, but not when it's a `Replacement`
- Is information about failed items within the batch returned when `ReportBatchItemFailures` is enabled maintained across deployments?

Cross-posted to AWS Forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=333823&tstart=0

Comment: What do you mean by checkpoint? Can you also tell us how you are deploying your lambda and what is the purpose of that checkpoint.

Comment: @KaiBurjack from what I understand he has a lambda that is constantly doing batch process and wants to deploy new version of that lambda. If that's the case then canary deployment could help. I wanna help but not sure if the issue is well explained for me to understand the scope

Comment: @sumek, yor are asking about kinesis correct ? checkpoint and ReportBatchItemFailures all are related to kinesis only ? correct me if i'm  wrong

Comment: In the link from @Ben "The calling service then updates the checkpoint value with the sequence number provided. If the batchItemFailures array is empty, the caller assumes all messages have been processed correctly. If the batchItemFailures array contains multiple items, the lowest sequence number is used as the checkpoint." Clearly, the checkpoint is a feature of the caller. It does not know or care which lambda processes what. Lambda can restart any time, there is no guarantee that one lambda instance will process everything.

Comment: Sorry everyone for abandoning the question. Will now try to clarify the question!

Comment: @Ben Checkpoint is the last position in the stream that was processed. It is a term used in Lambda documentation, eg: "When consuming and processing streaming data from an event source, by default Lambda checkpoints to the highest sequence number of a batch only when the batch is a complete success."

Comment: @ManishJaiswal I'm interested in Kinesis in particular, yes.

Comment: @sumek i have added my ans below check it out ! hope its useful to you !

Answer (score 0):

let help you from my experience of kafka/kinesis(aws).

**is the checkpoint maintaned?**
you redeploy lambda multiple times it doesn't matter if you committed checkpoint in kinesis, As you committed till the message you read to kinesis not to lambda.

- CheckPoints :- its essentially a mechanism allowing you to restart your process  from the last checkpointed position.

coming to your 2nd question, **it starts reading from the StartingPosition?**

- if you have committed checkpoint it won't start reading from start. it will start from where you had make last commit.

**Does ReportBatchItemFailures make any difference?**

- yes it does matter. Suppose your lambda code processing batch of records, when batch fails to process, only records after the last successful message are retried. This reduces duplicate records processing by your application and you have more controls to handle error failures.

Hope your doubts are bit clear now :)

Comment: The bit that is important for me would be to understand if CloudFormation `Replacement` wouldn't nuke the checkpoint